# How to set ICECC_VERSION when cross compiling with icecc

Tags: c++, linux, mingw, cross-compiling, distributed

I am trying to do cross-compilation with icecc, without luck. Right now, I am trying to compile for Windows on my Linux system using mingw, which works fine (even with ccache), but I am unable to get icecc to distribute the compilation correctly.

Unfortunately, the [icecc documentation](https://github.com/icecc/icecream#cross-compiling-using-icecream) is rather vague. For instance, what should "platform" in `ICECC_VERSION` be set to? Are there any valid/recognized values?

Currently I have created a native toolchain archive using:

```
icecc --build-native
```

...and an archive for my Ubuntu MinGW installation using:

```
/usr/lib/icecc/icecc-create-env --gcc /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-win32
```

I call the archive files `x86_64-gcc-5.4.0.tar.gz` and `win64-mingw-5.3.1.tar.gz`, respectively.

My `ICECC_VERSION` is (I just randomly picked "win64" as the platform name):

```
export ICECC_VERSION=/path/to/x86_64-gcc-5.4.0.tar.gz,win64:/path/to/win64-mingw-5.3.1.tar.gz
```

...and in my CMake toolchain file I have (as a temporary solution for trying things out):

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER icecc x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER icecc x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-win32)
```

With `export ICECC_DEBUG=debug` I get the following output when compiling a C++ file:

```
/usr/bin/icecc x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-win32 .....
...
ICECC[1287] 16:11:18: connected to /var/run/icecc/iceccd.socket
ICECC[1287] 16:11:18: <building_local>
ICECC[1287] 16:11:29: invoking: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-win32
ICECC[1287] 16:11:31: </building_local: 12379ms>
```

...so icecc does not seem to be distributing the build. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: For native compilation, I use ccache and `CCACHE_PREFIX=icecc`, which works just fine (building in a cluster of 15+ nodes), so icecc seems to be set up correctly.

**Update**: I believe that this behavior is caused by a [bug in ICECC](https://github.com/icecc/icecream/issues/164), which should now be [fixed](https://github.com/icecc/icecream/pull/165) in newer versions of ICECC.

Answer (score 2):

From the [README](https://github.com/icecc/icecream#cross-compiling-using-icecream)

> Create symbolic links with the cross compilers names (e.g.
>   arm-eabi-[gcc,g++] and arm-linux-androideabi-[gcc,g++]) pointing to
>   where the icecc binary is. Make sure these symbolic links are in the
>   $PATH and before the path of the toolchains.

Since you are using ccache, you have to add the following symbolic links to your cross compiler inside `/usr/lib/ccache`

Below is an example for an arm cross compiler

```
$ ls -al /usr/lib/ccache
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Apr 13 13:25 arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ -> ../../bin/ccache
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Apr 13 13:25 arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -> ../../bin/ccache
 .....
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem for me since I do not want to set up symbolic links on the build machine, but rather define everything via CMake and toolchain files (this makes the CI system more modular).